# PLSQL Command line parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am having a testing.sql program. First list line I receive the command line argument with `define run_date = '&1'`  and use it in cursor.

Argument I want it as string `'24/02/2011'` and I use it in comparison in sql queries and cursors.

```
Select * 
  from bill_file b 
 where to_char(b.initial_process_date_time,'DD/MM/YYYY')=&run_date;
```

When I call the script from [sqlplus](/questions/tagged/sqlplus) it's giving errors.  Not sure how I can receive string arguments.

Here is how I tried:

```
SQL> @testing.sql 24/02/2011
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for the info.  I enclosed the run_date in single quotes and it worked.
Select * from bill_file b where to_char(b.initial_process_date_time,'DD/MM/YYYY')='&run_date';

Comment: You'd probably be better off leaving `b.initial_process_date_time` as a date, and converting `run_date` into an Oracle date for the comparison. Particularly if the column is indexed as the `to_char` will prevent the index being used. Of course, as there's a time component you'd need to do it as a range, e.g. `where b.initial_process_date_time >= to_date('&run_date','DD/MM/YYYY') and b.initial_process_date_time < to_date('&run_date','DD/MM/YYYY') + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot quotes `@testing.sql "24/02/2011"`

Comment: You want single quotes for SQL string literal, @testing.sql '24/02/2011'

Answer (score 0):

Without the entirety of what you did, we can't say.

Here is how it simply works (without quotes in the call, but in the `to_date`):

> file c.sql

```
define run_date='&1';
select to_date('&run_date', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;
```

> Then the call:

```
SQL> @c.sql 24/02/2011
old   1: select to_date('&run_date', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual
new   1: select to_date('24/02/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual
24/02/2011
```